# Mediawiki: own Extension Specialpage - missing alias

Tags: php, mediawiki

I just tried to make my own wiki-extension following these tut: [Mediawiki - Develop Extensions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Developing_extensions)

The Extensions has a SpecialPage and when i visist the mediawiki - SpecialPages Site i get the following error:

```
[cb6b6dfb1a33d10f07bcbc44] /index.php/Spezial:Spezialseiten Wikimedia\Assert\ParameterAssertionException from line 63 of D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\vendor\wikimedia\assert\src\Assert.php: Bad value for parameter $dbkey: should not be empty

Backtrace:
#0 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\title\TitleValue.php(82):Wikimedia\Assert\Assert::parameter(boolean, string, string)
#1 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPage.php(100): TitleValue->__construct(integer, string, string)
#2 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPage.php(84): SpecialPage::getTitleValueFor(string, boolean, string)
#3 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPage.php(629): SpecialPage::getTitleFor(string, boolean)
#4 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\specials\SpecialSpecialpages.php(70): SpecialPage->getPageTitle()
#5 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\specials\SpecialSpecialpages.php(42): SpecialSpecialpages->getPageGroups()
#6 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPage.php(522): SpecialSpecialpages->execute(NULL)
#7 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPageFactory.php(576): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#8 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\MediaWiki.php(283): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#9 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\MediaWiki.php(851): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#10 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\MediaWiki.php(512): MediaWiki->main()
#11 D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\index.php(43): MediaWiki->run()
#12 {main}
```

with the Debug-notice:

```
Notice: Did not find alias for special page ''. Perhaps no aliases are defined for it? [Called from SpecialPageFactory::getLocalNameFor in D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\specialpage\SpecialPageFactory.php at line 691] in D:\Wiki\mediawiki\wiki\includes\debug\MWDebug.php on line 311
```

So why does it search for an empty alias ''  when trying to build my SpecialPage?

Could sth gone wrong with my MyExtensions.i18n.alias.php?
or Does any1 know if this kind of error has a deeper meening?

Comment: That's just a notice. The actual error is on the first line: *"Bad value for parameter $dbkey: should not be empty"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like an issue with the definition of your special page alias.

Make sure your alias for your SpecialPage is defined correctly, and that the alias page itself is properly attached in your extension in 'ExtensionMessagesFiles' (so it's being read).

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Special_pages#The_aliases_file for more information.

Also, you can use https://tools.wmflabs.org/mwstew/ tool to create an extension boilerplate with your special page name and alias generated for you.